# How to deploy Yii advanced application on Openshift?

Tags: php, yii, openshift, yii2

Can someone give me some general guidelines or point me to any source on how to deploy an advanced Yii template application v2 on OpenShift?

The problem is that I have not much experience with that platform and can not find specific documentation.

I can't access appdns/frontend or /backend (it gives me 404 error).

Comment: this topic help me with OpenShift structure and Yii2, see:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241846/how-to-set-up-different-document-roots-on-openshift-for-yii2-advanced-template

Answer (score 1):

Given that non-use OpenShift but I use another platform that does not provide access to the shell so I can not make the normal installation Yii2 commands  (composer and so on). I assume that you are my same condition. If you can be useful I depart from a copy of the entire application correctly configured on my local server and using ftp I transfer what is necessary. During the initial installation of course I transfer everything, then with a version control appropriately focused on my local copy I manage updates to be transferred to the server in the cloud. I hope this will be useful.